# Fourier transform of a triangular function

Tags: fourier-transform

How do I calculate Fourier Transform? I want to use the formula to calculate the Fourier transform, but I can not come to the right answer,anything wrong?

> [image]

Comment: Yes! If you cannot get the right answer then something's wrong.

Comment: you are right,i actually made  mistakes when i was calculating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in your plot is
$$f (t) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0 & t\le-1\\ 
1+t & -1<t\leq 0 \\
1-t & 0< t \leq 1 \\
0 & 1  <t. \\
\end{array}
\right. $$

Note that you can split the FT up into $4$ pieces, where two of them are zero. So
$$\mathcal{F}\{f\}(\omega) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-i\omega t}\,\mathrm{d}t = \int\limits_{-1}^{0}(1+t)e^{-i\omega t}\,\mathrm{d}t+\int\limits_{0}^{1}(1-t)e^{-i\omega t}\,\mathrm{d}t.$$
From now on this should be easy to solve. Multiply out, use linearity of the integral and solve four easy integrals of exponential functions.

Comment: thank you for your assitance